# Angular Admin Interface

Tags: angular, web

I am kinda new to Angular and programming overall (started this year) and I am building a web site using Angular (as a study project).

I would like to add an admin interface to edit the content of the site (title, text, etc...)

I was wondering if I could do that using some div "hidden" on the page that would appear when the admin logs in through the auth service, or I can only do that by "duplicating" the whole site so the auth guard redirect the admin to that part where he can edit everything or should I do a specific admin interface ala wordpress for instance.

I am not really looking for code but insights and best practices from more experienced than me people.

Thank you for reading, cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for me there're two options:

1.-Create a separate admin module and use loadChildren, so your typical routes becomes like:

```
const routes: Routes = [

  { path: 'One', Component:ComponentOne}
  ...
  { path: 'Admin', loadChildren: () => import('./admin/admin.module')
       .then(mod => mod.AdminModule) },
];
```

And your admin.router

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'Login', component: AdminLoginComponent },
  {
     path: '', component: AdminMainComponent, 
     canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],
     children: [...]
  }
]
```

2.-Change "each component" with a *ngIf, better is using a directive as [this Netanel Basal post](https://netbasal.com/the-power-of-structural-directives-in-angular-bfe4d8c44fb1),

the directive (I copy and paste)

```
@Directive({selector: '[ifRole]'})
export class IfRoleDirective {
  user$ : Subscription;
  @Input("ifRole") roleName : string;

  constructor( private templateRef : TemplateRef<any>,
               private viewContainer : ViewContainerRef,
               private authService : AuthService ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.user$ = this.authService.user
      .do(() => this.viewContainer.clear())
      .filter(user => user.role === this.roleName).subscribe(() => {
        this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.user$.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

And the use

```
<div *ifRole="'admin'">
  Only for Admin
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, the second option was more or like what I was thinking to resolve that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Implementation of some [admin] directive that depends on reactive data, and hide/show elements will be the good approach. You can apply it for elements, which you want to manage by current user's state.
However, if you have a banch of specific elements it is also good opportunity to implement stand-alone admin  module with corresponding views